# Name for technique of running two versions of code to ensure they are compatible?

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring

I am looking for a name to call this pattern that I have seen when maintaining legacy codebases.

Short version:

Run two versions of a function side-by-side, comparing results in the program itself, to ensure that changes to the new version remain compatible with the old version.

---

**Question: Is there a well-known name for this pattern?**

---

Long version:

- We need to change the internal implementation of some server function `foo`. For example, this could be for better performance, or to connect to a different database.
- We must not change what the function returns i.e. the function still does the same job, but with some change to how it is implemented.
- The function is in a production server environment, and must remain available at all times.
- There are no dev environments, unit tests, or well-defined requirements, and creating them is well outside of our budget.
- The change is simple enough that it is within our budget.

(I acknowledge that in this situation, many best practices have been overlooked. The pattern I describe is a pragmatic solution.)

So we do these steps:

1. Make two copies of `foo`, call them `foo_v1` and `foo_v2`.
2. Change `foo` so that it calls *both* `foo_v1` and `foo_v2`, and returns the result of `foo_v1`. From the outside, the only change is that it got slower, due to running 2 versions.
3. Change `foo` so that it compares the results of `foo_v1` and `foo_v2`. If they are different, this is logged.
4. Change `foo_v2` to do whatever the new requirement is, e.g. a performance improvement.
5. Because we are comparing the results of running both functions with real data, we can be confident that both versions do the same thing.
6. After some time has passed without detecting any differences, we copy the implementation of `foo_v2` into `foo`, and then delete `foo_v1` and `foo_v2`.

The key is that at all times the results come from a version of the function that we know is good.

I have used this pattern on a small scale when optimizing PHP functions which were making too many SQL queries. This [Stripe blog post](https://stripe.com/blog/online-migrations) describes a large project with some similarities. They used a Ruby library named [Scientist](https://github.com/github/scientist).

Comment: I think there's an element of the 'strangler fig' pattern/concept in there: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/StranglerFigApplication.html.

Comment: @DavidOsborne Thank you, that is correct at a high level, and through that site I found some related and more accurate descriptions of the pattern I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

[Verify Branch by Abstraction](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BranchByAbstraction.html) is the closest match I could find. It describes having two implementations in production, comparing the results of both within the execution of the program.

[Branch by Abstraction](https://www.stevesmith.tech/blog/application-pattern-verify-branch-by-abstraction/) is a more well-known and well-referenced refactoring technique, but lacks the automated verification of results.

[StranglerFigApplication](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/StranglerFigApplication.html) appears to be a similar concept, but at the higher level of system architecture, and so it is loosely applicable to this situation.